# deploy odoo app with support of odoo 10 and odoo 11

Tags: deployment, odoo, odoo-10

I developed an app that support odoo 10 and odoo 11 both and I want to deploy this app under one deployment. Mean If I visit my odoo apps I should see one app not two apps and when I select version from drop down, it should show me app of the respective version. like this app/module [magento odoo 10](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/hexcode_magento_odoo/)
If I search this module in odoo apps it shows me only one entry there but when I change odoo version it show this as two modules both for odoo 10 and odoo 11 with different prices
[magento odoo 11](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/hexcode_magento_odoo/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a account in GitHub
2. Create a repository with any title
3. Create Two branches namely '10' and '11'
   [image]
4. Push your code to the respective branches
5. Login to Odoo apps with your credentials
6. Go to My Dashboard and add your Git repository URL for both branches. Then click on scan now button. Both versions will be added
   [image]
7. Then add the necessary details for the module. You will be able to see both versions of your module.

Comment: Thanks. I had already created branches as 10.0 and 11.0. I used different name for modules(folder) in both branches. It came up that module folder name should be same in both branches.